# Which facebook-plugin is the right one for perfect facebook integration in grails 1.3.7?

Tags: java, facebook, grails, facebook-graph-api, groovy

I have a grails 1.3.7 project with spring security installed. Now i want some facebook features. Until today i don't use spring security for the users login, it's only to secure my backend for the admins.

I want my users to login with facebook connect, and i want to read some data over the graph api.

There are many ways how to do this within grails. I could use some of the facebook plugins or just use some of the java facebook librarys... what would you do? wich plugin would you choose?

thank you very much!
whitenexx

Answer (score 2):

For authentication you can use [`spring-security-facebook`](https://github.com/pinut/grails-spring-security-facebook) plugin.

The plugin also gives you Facebook `acess_token`, that you can use for reading data from Facebook. For calling Facebook API you can take `spring-social-facebook` plugin, or just a [Spring Social library](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social).

Comment: Thanks for your good comment! I'm very undecided wich plugin is the best for me, but it looks like spring social is the best choice for future support, isn't it? The plugin by pinut looks very good too....hmmm very hard to decide and pick the right one!

Comment: but is it possible to use spring-security-facebook plugin with grails 1.3.7?

Comment: I'm not sure, I didn't test latest plugin versions against 1.3.7, and require 2.0+. But you can make your own copy, and fix incompatibilities with 1.3.7, if any exists

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Your plugin works well but I only get cookies of session lifetime. what do I have to do to get cookies that last longer than the browser session?

Comment: Seems that you can't control cookie lifetime. But you can use Server-Side authentication instead (see plugin docs)

Answer (score 1):

I have had pretty good luck with the spring social media plugins.

http://grails.org/plugin/spring-social-core
http://grails.org/plugin/spring-social-facebook

Pretty robust.  The key with this plugin is setting up the callback url.  We do it like:

```
<% callback = request.forwardURI.minus(request.getContextPath())

if (request.getQueryString()) 
    callback += '?' + request.getQueryString() %>

<g:set var="ss_oauth_redirect_callback" value="${callback}" scope="session"/>
```

I am very interested in other folk's feedback!

Comment: Thanks for comment! Looks like spring-social-core plugin is the correct one for me. But where do you define the callback url? In wich view and why? Am I able to use the graph API with spring social too, or do i have to use an other library for graph api?

Comment: you need to define the ss_oauth_redirect_callback in the scope of your page.  It is the page that the oauth returns to.